# Get text before current cursor position at CKEditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

This is my first question. I did not find any results despite my research. I have two problems with CKEditor.

**First Problem;**

I want to get 20 character before the current cursor position at CKEditor.

**Second Problem;**

Sometimes I add words with code. But old cursor position is valid.

**Thanks for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

Is there no one to help?This is very important for me